# ArrayList changing after sorting function

Tags: object, arraylist

I have just started utilizing ArrayLists in some C# code and am having some problems when sorting.

First I define create an ArrayList object under my class:

```
ArrayList cutList = new ArrayList;
```

Then I set and sort the array list to find the minimum:

```
cutList.Add("2200","1800","1200","1");
int minList = (int)GetMinValue(cutList);
```

Using the function:

```
public static object GetMinValue(ArrayList arrList)
{
ArrayList sortArrayList = arrList;
sortArrayList.Sort();
return sortArrayList[0];
}
```

Later I try to find the index cutList[2] and I find "1200" because the function also sorted cutList.  I have also had the same problem in the past, when I set a variable to an Application settings and then the Applications setting changes when I modify the variable.  How to I correctly fix these problems.  I have been learning C# on my own and am guilty of skipping around a little bit.  Is there a lesson on Objects that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code is that `ArrayList sortArrayList = arrList;` does not copy `arrList` to  `sortArrayList`: the assignment merely creates a new alias for the existing object. To make your code work, use

```
ArrayList sortArrayList = (ArrayList)arrList.Clone();
```

I must add that this is probably the most inefficient way of looking up the min element in a list, and also a rather archaic container. I would prefer using `List<string>` instead of `ArrayList`, and using LINQ's `Min()` function to get the minimum element.

Comment: I have done some more research and found some sources discussing "pass by reference".  So does the Clone() function allow to create it's own memory locations instead of pointing to the same memory "reference", which changes when cutList or arrList changes?  The reason why I used ArrayList for the job is so I could hopefully learn more about ArrayList.  Looks like my lesson is I should not use them for sorting to find min/max.....

Comment: `Clone()` creates a copy which is independent of its original. You can sort the copy, add elements to it, or clear it out - nothing is going to happen to the original. Naturally, the changes to the original will not be reflected in the copy either.